# Simple update query NOT updating. No exceptions, no errors. Just... nothing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, razor

I am trying to do a very simple update, but is proving to be very difficult. I don't know what is going on; it just doesn't update:

Here's my update code:

```
if(Request.QueryString["Action"] == "Update")
{
    var InPage = Request["InPage"];
    var PositionInPage = Request["PositionInPage"];
    var CategoryName = Request["CategoryName"];
    var ImagePath = Request["ImagePath"];
    database.Execute("UPDATE Categories SET PositionInPage = " +
                     PositionInPage + ", InPage = " + InPage +
                     " WHERE CategoryName = '" + CategoryName +
                     "' AND ImagePath = '" + ImagePath + "'");
    Response.Redirect("~/Fashion.cshtml");
}
```

Here's the form code:

```
<form method="post" action="Update.cshtml?Action=Update">
    <input type="hidden" name="CategoryName" value="@Request.QueryString["CategoryName"]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ImagePath" value="@Request.QueryString["ImagePath"]" />
    <label for="InPage">Move to Page</label>
    <input type="text" name="InPage" value="@Request.QueryString["InPage"]" style="background-color: White;" />
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="PositionInPage">Position In Page</label>
    <input type="text" name="PositionInPage" value="@Request.QueryString["PositionInPage"]" style="background-color: White;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: White;" />
</form>
```

I have checked that the QueryString is populated when the page is first reached and that the form variables are submitted upon clicking submit.

I have even put the DB query in a try catch statement and outputted any exceptions, but there are never any exceptions to catch.

But still nothing updates.

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: build the sql statement into a separate var so you can inspect the final product, then run it through your db's interface console and see if that works. Given there's no errors, most likely the WHERE clause is not matching what you think it should be.

Comment: Use SQL Profile to see what happened...

Comment: You are open for SQL-Injection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx (outdated but still valid)

Comment: check your database may following coditions not met even if condition not met update execute successfully

Comment: Well, I have checked that the WHERE clause matches whats in the database, but it just still doesn't update - and nothing

Answer (score 5):

an update can successfully update 0 rows.  I would triple check your WHERE clause to see if it is actually trying to match existing rows.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect that there's a problem with the ImagePath part of the WHERE clause because it contains "/"'s (without the quotes) - would that make any difference?

Comment: simplify your test by having a row with NULL in that field - might help narrow it down.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Try fixing it like this:

```
database.Execute(
    "UPDATE Categories " +
    "SET PositionInPage = @0, InPage = @1 " + 
    "WHERE CategoryName = @2 AND ImagePath = @3", 

    PositionInPage, 
    InPage, 
    CategoryName, 
    ImagePath
);
```

Now that you have fixed the vulnerability ensure that the values of `CategoryName` and `ImagePath` you are passing in the WHERE clause actually match some records in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an "instead of" trigger on the target table? In SQL Server if they encounter an error you won't hear about it in your update will not happen.

Comment: Instead of trigger? That's new to me! I'll go look it up - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the WHERE clause condition. I think it can be improved:

- Try to have a unique numerical (auto number)/GUID ID for your category table.
- Use this ID in your update instead of using the text columns (categoryName, imagePath).